# Problem entering values to a struct with double pointers

Tags: c, struct, append, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have to use double pointer in the function for filling elements to the struct (the function must be void). But it doesn't print anything. I assume that the problem is with passing the right address but cannot find it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nums{
    int num;
    struct nums *ptr;
}sNums;

void addRecords(sNums** head);
sNums* createRecord();
void prinrecords(sNums* head);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    sNums* head=NULL;
    printf("%d\n", &head);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        addRecords(&head);
    }
    system ("pause");
}
```

This is the function for printing the stored elements:

```
void prinrecords(sNums* head){
    while(head!=NULL){
        printf("{%d} ", head->num);
        head=head->ptr;
    }
}
```

Here is the function for adding elements using a double pointer:

```
void addRecords(sNums** head){
    sNums* temp_new=createRecord();
    sNums* fst_position;
    fst_position=*head;
    printf("%d\n", fst_position);
    if (fst_position == NULL)
    {
        fst_position=temp_new;
        return ;
    }
    while(fst_position->ptr!=NULL){
    fst_position=fst_position->ptr;
    }
    fst_position->ptr=temp_new; 
}

sNums* createRecord(){
    sNums *new=(sNums*)malloc(sizeof(sNums));
    printf("Enter Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &new->num);
    new->ptr=NULL;
    return new;
}
```

Comment: when you want to print an address use the format `%p`. *addRecords* have to assign `*head`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet

```
fst_position=*head;
//...
if (fst_position == NULL)
{
    fst_position=temp_new;
    return ;
}
```

does not change the passed by reference the head pointer. It changes the local variable `fst_position`.

The function can be defined the following way

```
void addRecords(sNums** head)
{
    while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->ptr;

    *head = createRecord();
}
```

That is all. Only two statements. :)

Though in general the design of the functions is not good. For example entering numbers that will be added to the list should be outside the function `createRecord`.

Moreover allocation of memory can fail. In this case your program will have undefined behavior.

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows how your functions can be redesigned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nums
{
    int num;
    struct nums *ptr;
} sNums;

int addRecords(sNums** head, int num );
sNums* createRecord();
void prinrecords( const sNums* head );

sNums * createRecord( int num ) 
{
    sNums *node = malloc( sizeof( sNums ) );

    if ( node != NULL )
    {
        node->num = num;
        node->ptr = NULL;
    }

    return node;
}

int addRecords( sNums** head, int num )
{
    sNums *node = createRecord( num );
    int success = node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->ptr;

        *head = node;
    }

    return success;
}

void prinrecords( const sNums *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->ptr )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->num );
    }
    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    sNums* head = NULL;
    const size_t N = 10;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i )
    {
        int num;

        printf( "Enter a number: " );
        scanf( "%d", &num );

        addRecords( &head, num );
    }

    prinrecords( head );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a number: 0
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 6
Enter a number: 7
Enter a number: 8
Enter a number: 9
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```

Answer (score 1):

You want that doing the minimal changes :

```
void addRecords(sNums** head){
  sNums* temp_new=createRecord();

  if (*head == NULL)
    *head = temp_new;
  else {
    sNums* fst_position = *head;

    while(fst_position->ptr!=NULL){
      fst_position=fst_position->ptr;
    }
    fst_position->ptr=temp_new; 
  }
}
```

else you never save the first cell nor the next of course because you always start from an empty list without modifying it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nums{
    int num;
    struct nums *ptr;
}sNums;

void addRecords(sNums** head);
sNums* createRecord();
void prinrecords(sNums* head);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    sNums* head=NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        addRecords(&head);
    }
    prinrecords(head);
    putchar('\n');
}

void prinrecords(sNums* head){
    while(head!=NULL){
        printf("{%d} ", head->num);
        head=head->ptr;
    }
}

void addRecords(sNums** head){
  sNums* temp_new=createRecord();

  if (*head == NULL)
    *head = temp_new;
  else {
    sNums* fst_position = *head;

    while(fst_position->ptr!=NULL){
      fst_position=fst_position->ptr;
    }
    fst_position->ptr=temp_new; 
  }
}

sNums* createRecord(){
    sNums *new=(sNums*)malloc(sizeof(sNums));
    printf("Enter Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &new->num);
    new->ptr=NULL;
    return new;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall a.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter Number: 1
Enter Number: 2
Enter Number: 3
{1} {2} {3} 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `addRecords` function doesn't change the given `head` pointer when it creates a new list (i.e. the first time it is called)! You should do this, instead:

```c
void addRecords(sNums** head)
{
    sNums* temp_new = createRecord();
    sNums* fst_position;
    fst_position = *head;
//  printf("%d\n", fst_position);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)(fst_position));/// Let's keep the format/argument arrangement cool!
    if (fst_position == NULL) {
    //  fst_position = temp_new; // This WON'T change the 'head' pointer...
        *head = temp_new;        // ... but this will!
        return;
    }
    while (fst_position->ptr != NULL) {
        fst_position = fst_position->ptr;
    }
    fst_position->ptr = temp_new;
    // Here, we don't change the 'head' pointer, so its OK!
}
```

Note: See the change I made to your pointer reporting line: using the `%d` format specifier for a pointer argument is undefined behaviour and will cause all sorts of ugly issues on platforms where a pointer is not the same size as an `int`.

Note 2: To avoid warnings (and possible errors) on strict, standard-conforming compilers, you should add `void` inside the parentheses for your `createRecord` function, to specify that it takes no parameter:

```c
sNums* createRecord(void);
```

Without this, the `clang-cl` compiler (for example) will give you this advice:

> message : this declaration is not a prototype; add 'void' to make it a
>   prototype for a zero-parameter function

And, finally:

> *But it doesn't print anything.*

That's because you never call `prinrecords`! Add the call to your `main` function:

```c
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    sNums* head = NULL;
    printf("%p\n", (void*)(&head));// Keep format/agument cool!
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        addRecords(&head);
    }
    prinrecords(head); // You forgot this!
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```